# Высота блока зависит от display свойства

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
 .promo__display {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px; }


  .promo__doit {
    padding-left: 26px; 
    margin-bottom: 32px; 
    margin: 0px; }
```

```html
<div class="promo__doit promo__display">
                <h1 class="promo__h1">DO IT NOW</h1>
                <h4 class="promo__h4">Or You Never Get It Back</h4>
            </div>
```

Высота блока выделена синим. Из всех манипуляций выяснил, что если убрать `display: inline-block;` то высота блока будет по содержимому, но так и не понял почему `display` так влияет на высоту, раньше этого не замечал, в чём тут причина?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вертикальные margin у элементов h1 и h4, которые в браузере идут по умолчанию? И еще, в этом нет смысла:

```
margin-bottom: 32px; 
margin: 0px;
```

Вы задаете в начале нижний margin, а потом его же сбрасываете стенографическим свойством.

Comment: Это все результаты того что я пробовал разобрать, просто мусор остался.
H1 и H4 вроде как не причем, смотрел сколько они занимают места, там все нормально

Comment: Ну, еще может быть то, что при значении inline-block вертикальные margin не схлопываются и не выпадают из родительского контейнера, а при block выпадают, это поведение блочных боксов по умолчанию в браузерах. Так что это тоже учитывайте.